# Evaluate the Series with certain property

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I want to have any hint!!

First i tried to replacement $x$ to $\frac{k}{n}$. But result is not good.

Comment: Try setting $x = k/n^2$ instead

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, Since the first sum is in terms of $n$ and the second in terms of $k$, it should be $x = 1/k$ instead.  Then, if the names $n$ and $k$ are swapped, the sums would be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that you don't get confused rewrite the given equation as

$$\frac{\pi}{12}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}\cos(kx)=\frac{x^2}{4}$$

and the limit we want to compute as $$\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}\cos(k/m).$$

This rewriting is just giving a different name to the dummy variable in the given equation, and to the dummy variable in the limit we want to compute.

So, what we need to do is to put $x:=1/m$ in the first equation.

We get $$\frac{\pi}{12}-\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}\cos(k/m)-\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}\cos(k/m)=\frac{1}{4m^2}.$$

Now, take limits as $m\rightarrow\infty$. Use that the series above converges to be able to say that is the limit of the term $\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}\cos(k/m)$.

Comment: And you refer that function is uniformly convergent.